# Database update from Oracle 9g to Oracle 11i. What are the appropriate .dll’s for .net MVC 4.5 web application using Nhibernate?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, razor-2

Oracle Database is being updated where I work, and I need to know how this will affect .net Application that uses Nhibernation for Mapping to the database.

I basically need to know what appropriate Nhibernate dll files for update from Oracle 9g to Oracle 11i.

What changes would have to be made on the Web.config file?

What dll files are needed in the  output directory?

The only online Document I found online was; http://nhibernate.info/doc/tutorials/first-nh-app/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.html

However this online example uses a Microsoft SQL Database.

Comment: Google "nhibernate documentation" - first hit: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/.  Note, it's not the best documentation in the world, so I don't know if it contains the information you need or not.  It at least mentions a few different dialects for various Oracle versions.  Please update your question after at least investigating this documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless you are going to start using the new features of 11g, then I'm pretty sure nothing needs to change.

Comment: I'm Updating from 9g to 11i. I'm not sure what the differences are between g and i. I think nothing should be change as well, but I think that there's a different type of features implemented in Oracle 11i than Oracle 9g.